# Dynamic value from TextBox to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox

So i created a dynamic `TextBox` which allows the user to enter a description if requested, however I would like to populate my table with the description from the user. e.g.

```cs
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = textDescription.Text
```

But every time I do this, the `testDescription` name isn't available, I was wondering if there was any way to solve this issue.

Just want to say that my meaning of dynamic means i created the `TextBox` myself and not drag and drop.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textDescription = new TextBox();
    this.Controls.Add(textDescription);
    textDescription.Location = new Point(180, 190);
    textDescription.Size = new Size(154, 20);
    textDescription.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
    textDescription.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create that `TextBox` each time you click that `Button`. Instead, create a class level variable `textDescription` of `TextBox` type, create a new instance in the constructor and set `Visible = false` in addition to the other properties shown in your snippet, add it to the `Controls` collection of the `Form`. In the `button1_Click` event, you just need to show the control: `textDescription.Visible = true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the TextBox is a local variable in "button1_Click". Maybe you can try to define it as a global variable.

```
TextBox textDescription = new TextBox();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Add(textDescription);
    textDescription.Location = new Point(180, 190);
    textDescription.Size = new Size(154, 20);
    textDescription.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
    textDescription.Text = "123";
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textDescription.Text;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code it works, but when the input gets displayed on the table, it displays "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: Hello", was wondering if you know how to get rid of the text except "Hello"

Comment: It seems that you output a control "TextBox", rather than the property "TextBox.Text".